# Using RCP application Help menu item to navigate to website

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I just started working with the RCP application main menu and I want to link up a menu entry to a website address such that when the user clicks on the menu entry the internet browser is launched with the website. I am using Eclipse 3.8.1. I attempted to use the org.eclipse.browser.openBrowser command but I can't see how that can help me in this situation

Comment: Eclipse 3.4 is over 9 years old, I doubt anyone remembers what works and what doesn't on such an old release.

Comment: unfortunately I have to make it work on eclipse 3.x. We wont be moving to eclipse 4.x anytime soon although I am using Mars 2.

Comment: Even in Eclipse 3 releases there is Eclipse 3.8.1 which is 4 years newer than 3.4

Comment: sorry we are on 3.8.1 my bad the plugin.xml header showing 3.4 was a copy paste most probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workbench browser support should be able to do this:

```
IWorkbenchBrowserSupport support = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport();

IWebBrowser browser = support.getExternalBrowser();

URL url = ... url you want to open
browser.openURL(url);
```

Comment: yup that's what i was just trying to do. Thanks Greg